# AdMob test ad's shows correctly real add does not show

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

There are some cases with the issue of showing Admob. But they did not help. So implementation is that in MyApp.java I am starting the downloading video and initialize instance.

```
mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(context.
                    getString(R.string.ad_unit_id_real),
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Then in regular activity I am with help of that instance checking if videoAd is loaded. And then show it to the user. Here is the code

```
if (MyApp.mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){
                        showAdDialog();
                    }
```

I have added my Id's in Manifest. My test video works correctly. But real video is not working? Does that means the problem in the code? Or I need to make something on Ad account side?

It might help. I was trying to debug it but couldnt figure out can it be the reason of the issue
[image]

Comment: real ads will only show on production apps.... meaning if you use your production key on an app you built from Android Studio, then it will NOT show a prod ad. You have to build a signed APK and then run it with the production key.

Comment: @soldfor i did. it is published on playmarket and I upload it on real device as apk